# Issues in hyperlink to an external document

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, external-files, xr

I have two latex files: one for the actual paper and one for the appendix. In the paper, I want to refer to section of the appendix. I follow what I found around on referring to external dcouments but I can't make it work.

This is my template for the paper (pdf name: `Paper.pdf`):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
      
\usepackage{xr-hyper}  
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,pdfstartview=FitH,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref} %option dvipdfm for dvi

\externaldocument{OnlineAppendix}[OnlineAppendix.pdf] % reference to the online appendix

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}\label{sec:intro}

I want to refer to \autoref{sec: app} but it doesn't work.

\end{document}
```

This is so the online appendix (pdf names: `OnlineAppendix.pdf`):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}  
     
\usepackage{xr-hyper} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\externaldocument{Paper}[Paper.pdf] % actual paper

\begin{document}

\section{Title}\label{sec: app}
This is the Online Appendix

\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: your examples are way too long. Create in a test folder copies and then remove all unnecessary packages and code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you for your tip, I edited the question and made it more manageable

Comment: The reference in the pdf is correct, but links to files are not reliably supported by pdf viewers. It works for me e.g. only in adobe reader. sumatra has a clickable link but to the wrong location, and in the pdf viewer in the browser the link is not active at all (while url links work there).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That's interestin, I will need to check which packages cause issues to my output then

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It's very weird, if I run the code above I just see `??`. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: compile every document twice and then show the log-files.

Comment: is the log-file the same as `synctex.gz` that is generated in my folder when compilig?

Comment: no the log-file is the file ending with `.log`.

Comment: it's not in my folder I am afraid

Comment: which editor do you use?

Comment: I use `pdfLatex`

Comment: pdflatex is not an editor. Where do you type your tex files?

Comment: `TeXworks` from `MiKTeX2.9`

Comment: go to the properties, the tab for the various profiles, and check if the pdflatex profile you are using has a --clean option or something like this and remove it.